# Default value from Option<String>

Tags: rust

How can I return a default value from an `Option<&String>`?

This is my sample/minimal code:

```
fn main() {
    let map = std::collections::HashMap::<String, String>::new();

    let result = map.get("").or_else(|| Some("")).unwrap(); // <== I tried lots of combinations
    
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

I know I could do something like this...

```
let value = match result {
    Some(v) => v,
    None => "",
};
```

... but I want to know if it is possible to implement it in a one-liner with `or_else` or `unwrap_or_else`?
(It is important to make the default value lazy, so it does not get computed if it is not used)

---

These are some of the compiler suggestions I tried (I can put them all because SO won't allow me):

```
7 | let result = map.get("").or_else(|| Some("") ).unwrap();
  |                                          ^^ expected struct `String`, found `str`
```

.

```
7 | let result = map.get("").or_else(|| Some(&"".to_string()) ).unwrap();
  |                                     ^^^^^^--------------^
  |                                     |     |
  |                                     |     temporary value created here
  |                                     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

.

```
7 | let result = map.get("").or_else(|| Some(String::new()) ).unwrap();
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                                          |
  |                                          expected `&String`, found struct `String`
  | 

                                     help: consider borrowing here: `&String::new()`
```

.

```
7 | let result = map.get("").or_else(|| Some(&String::new()) ).unwrap();
  |                                     ^^^^^^-------------^
  |                                     |     |
  |                                     |     temporary value created here
  |                                     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

.
and also

```
6 |     let result = map.get("").unwrap_or_else(|| ""); // I tried lots
  |                                                ^^ expected struct `String`, found `str`
  |
  = note: expected reference `&String`
             found reference `&'static str`
```

Comment: Please **always** post the full error message. Even if we can find it out ourselves, this can save us time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a default &str for HashMap<\_, String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887322/returning-a-default-str-for-hashmap-string)

Answer (score 6):

If you really need a `&String` as the `result`, you may create a `String` for the default value with lifetime that's long enough.

```rust
fn main() {
    let map = std::collections::HashMap::<String, String>::new();

    let default_value = "default_value".to_string();
    let result = map.get("").unwrap_or(&default_value);
    
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

If the default value is a compile-time fixed value, the allocation of `default_value` can be avoided by using `&str` instead.

```rust
fn main() {
    let map = std::collections::HashMap::<String, String>::new();
    let result = map.get("")
        .map(String::as_str)
        .unwrap_or("default_value");

    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, it works! To be honest, I do not know if I need `&String`, it is the type returned by `map.get(...)` so I have it all around. It seems I will need to understand the differences between `String`, `&String`, `str`, `&str` and all the combinations. Thanks again!

Comment: `.as_deref()` is more concise than `.map(String::as_str)` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I return a default value from an Option<&String>?

It's not trivial because as you've discovered ownership gets in the way, as you need an actual `String` to create an `&String`. The cheap and easy solution to that is to just have a static empty `String` really:

```rust
static DEFAULT: String = String::new();

fn main() {
    let map = std::collections::HashMap::<String, String>::new();

    let result = map.get("").unwrap_or(&DEFAULT); // <== I tried lots of combinations
    
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

`String::new` is const since 1.39.0, and does not allocate, so this works fine. If you want a non-empty string as default value it's not as good a solution though.

The cleaner and more regular alternative is to "downgrade" (or upgrade, depending on the POV) the `&String` to an `&str`:

```rust
let result = map.get("").map(String::as_str).unwrap_or("");
```

or

```rust
let result = map.get("").map(|s| &**s).unwrap_or("");
```

it's really not like you're losing anything here, as `&String` is not much more capable than `&str` (it does offer a few more thing e.g. `String::capacity`, but for the most part it exists on genericity grounds e.g. `HashMap::<K, V>::get` returns an `&V`, so if you store a `String` you get an `&String` makes sense even though it's not always quite the thing you want most).